# Getting Error while fetching data location wise with $near query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, geometry

```
query = {
  "location" : {
       "$near" : {
                    "$geometry": {
                        "type": "Point" ,
                        "coordinates": [18.55,73.78]
                    }
                }
            }
       }
  }






planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:443:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
    at processMessage (D:\Projects\api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:364:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:533:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  ok: 0,
```

For this I have created **2dsphere** on location field as specified in the below link

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/

```
db.collectionName.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )
```

Help me to understand If I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: try changing `$near` to `$nearSphere` and also add `$minDistance: 0` and `$maxDistance: yourmaxdistance` next to `$geometry` if it still doesnt work

Comment: Thanks for the info @AshwynHorton .. I have tried with $nearSphere also.. but still getting same error.

Comment: Cool cool, let me know if it helps ey...

Comment: yeah.. tried with this $nearSphere.. but not working.. still getting same error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing `$near` to `$nearSphere` and also add `$minDistance: 0` and `$maxDistance: yourmaxdistance` next to `$geometry` if it still doesnt work...so it will look like

```
query = {
  location: {
     $nearSphere: {
        $geometry: {
            type: "Point" ,
            coordinates: [18.55,73.78],
        },
        $minDistance: 0,
        $maxDistance: //your max will go here
     }
  }
}
```

If the above does not work try creating the index again and keep a look out for the output...

Here is an example of an index creation that did not work...

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unknown index plugin '2dSphere'",
        "code" : 67,
        "codeName" : "CannotCreateIndex",
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1590940517, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1590940517, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,""),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("")
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Tried with this $nearSphere and also with minDistance and maxDistance but as it is optional So giving same error..

Comment: okay, have you tried creating the index again...theres an output you get from creating the index that confirms that it has been created...let me edit to show an example

Comment: Yes Dude I have created Index. I have checked it also -                                                    

{
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "location" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "location_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "DEV_DB.items",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    }